# how to load the local file in react native ios webview

Tags: react-native-ios

local files are not loading in ios, in android its working fine, using,
react-native-webview version 5.0.1

```
<WebView
                        source={{ uri: 'ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html'}}
                        ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
                        originWhitelist={'["*"]'}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        domStorageEnabled={true}
                        scrollEnabled={false}
                        onLoad={() => this.sendPostMessage()}
                        allowFileAccess={true}
                        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                        allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
                        useWebKit={true}
                    />
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to indicate what "unable" means? Are you getting an error, or no response where you expect one?

Answer (score 0):

try using this

Loading local file

```
const FileHTML = require('./Index.html');

<WebView
  source={FileHTML}
  style={{flex: 1}}
 />
```

you can write like

```
<WebView source={{ html: HTML, baseUrl: 'web/' }} />
```

This code is working for me android ios

```
import {Platform, WebView} from 'react-native';    

<WebView
  source={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 
    require('../src/assets/your.html') :
    {uri: 'file:///android_asset/your.html'}
  }
  domStorageEnabled
  javaScriptEnabled
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ios for local files to be accessed, you need to include them in the `Copy Bundle Resources` section in XCode.

1. Click on you project name in the Xcode's left pane.
2. In the center pane, select your app target
3. Click on `Build Phases` tab on top
4. Scroll to `Copy Bundle Resources` section and click `+`
5. Find your file in the list. If not found Click on `Add other` option and locate it.
6. Then in your code change source prop of webview as:

```
  source={{ uri: 'ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html', baseUrl: './'}}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi thank you, i got stuck with other issue, im downloading some file and storing it in LibraryDirectoryPath, i can able to load that file in simulator, but its not loading in ios device